# Rails upgrade from 5.0 to 5.1 - Cannot start webrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have upgraded yesterday my app under development from Rails 5.0 to 5.1. Everything went smoothly and was working (but my webrick server was already started)

Today I tried to launch webrick and got an error:

```
c:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_
matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `raise_in_transactional_cal
lbacks=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: sorry indeed duplicate. `config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true` should be commented out in Rails 5.1

Comment: I wonder why people don't search the same on SO first before posting the question

Comment: The answer is first result on google

Comment: I think I skipped when I saw it was 2yo :( my mistake

Comment: No worries! :)
Actually, these kind of answers will work for you even if they are more than 5 years old unless they are version specific

Comment: Sometimes, Even the answers from 2010 help me